# convert  date time from one timezone to another in android

Tags: android, timezone

I am using smack api for instance messages.I want to send the current time with the messages.So i have set the current time as message subject.and then get that time on receiver side.But the problem is that message subject should be string so i have convert the date time to string at sender side and then again convert from string to date time on receiver side.I want the sender's date time should be convert as per receiver's Timezone.I have wrote the code as below but i can't convert the date time to receiver's Timezone's date time.

```
//sender side
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
String strdt= formatter.format(c.getTime());
message.setSubject(strdt);
```

receiver side

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
String strzone=tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
String str=message.getSubject();
Date expiry = null;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
                 formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(strzone));
        try { 
                expiry = formatter.parse(str);
                  }
          catch (Exception e) 
                {e.printStackTrace();}

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(strzone));  
String formattedDate1= df.format(expiry);  
Log.i("receiving time",formattedDate1);
```

i got one output like

message subject=>  Wed Aug 22 13:35:13 GMT+00:00 2012

after convert from string to date =>  Wed Aug 22 07:35:13 MDT 2012

after set the time zone of receiver => Wed Aug 22 06:35:13 GMT-07:00 2012

actual receiver side time => Wed Aug 22 06:39:56 MDT 2012

**Edit**

Actually i want to send the sender's time to receiver and on receiver side the should be convert as per receiver's time zone.as describe above the receiver's actual time is different than the converting time.So please if you have different code then please post here.

Comment: please share sample date, You can also use Z but depends on your data, check this documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Use plain longs for time. (Long.toString(new Date().getTime()). It does not contain (nor need) any TZ info, and is therefore more flexible.

Comment: but this will only pass the time right?Can i get the date and time from this long value? like in this formate "22 Aug 2012  06:20 Am"

Comment: rtfm, and see that getTime returns the number of millis since epoch. You don't need to format it unless you need it to follow a standard or for user interface.

Comment: i want to show this time in user interface.So i need to convert from milliseconds to my specific format.So it is required to set the receiver's timezone on receiver side when i convert from long value to date and time?

Comment: i would advise to format at the last moment (when the display is about to take place), and not in the communication layer

Comment: when i get the message subject it will automatically convert the long time to like" Wed Aug 22 07:36:20 Mountain Daylight Time 2012" so how can i convert this time to receiver's date and time?

Comment: don't set the subject to a formatted string representing the time. set it to the long value of the time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15671/discussion-between-nency-and-njzk2)